# Do instance variables in Python have to be initialized in the __init__ method for a Class?

Tags: python, class, pyserial

Why is it if I don't set `self.ser = False` first, I cannot pass around the `self.ser` variable as a handle to write with `pyserial`?

```
import serial
import time

class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self, port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baud=9600):
        self.baud = baud
        self.port = port
        self.ser = False

    def connect(self):
        """Opens serial connection to Device"""
        self.ser = serial.Serial(self.port, self.baud, timeout=.5)

    def writeuart(self, message):
        self.ser.flushInput()
        self.ser.write(message)
        time.sleep(1)
        return self.ser.read(self.ser.inWaiting())
```

So in other words, can I not create `self.ser` from within the `connect()` method and then make use of `self.ser` in other methods of the same class?

Comment: Yes, you can, as long as `connect` is called before any other methods that use `self.ser` (including methods in other classes). If you don't do this you'll get `AttributeErrors` when trying to assess `self.ser`.

Comment: Please fix the indentation for the class methods.

Comment: No, they don't. But if you're having a specific problem or error, it would help if you provided example and traceback. Otherwise, see @101 comment above for simple explanation. You may be getting errors if you're calling on `self.ser` before it's instantiated.

Comment: If you don't want to do the connect in `__init__` maybe test the value of `self.ser` before using it in `writeuart` and raise an exception if its an invalid value. I'd probably use `None` rather than `False` as the invalid value.

Comment: @DavidZemens Understood, I had to keep the code general in this case though, which meant no stack trace as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
def __init__(self, port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baud=9600):
    self.baud = baud
    self.port = port
    self.connect()       # it's ok
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13110207)

Comment: @ViralSavaj: If you compare the code to that in the original, I believe Chang is trying to say that `self.connect()` should be called instead of defining `self.ser = False`.  The answer could stand some improvement, but I believe it *is* an attempt.

Comment: @Chang_Jian: The only problem here is that I don't want the connect() to happen until the calling script needs the device connected. In theory, there would be several of these and I need to keep the control of connecting and disconnecting disjointed from the object creation. But, this does illustrate a means to do so.

Comment: If you want to control of these actions,  you can let `self.connect()` return a serial object.  Method may change the name called like : `def get_connection()` or something else.